# AngularJS ngModel directive in select

Tags: select, angularjs

I am working on an angularjs project and i have a problem with the `ngModel` not binding within the select.But the same concept is working in another select tag and in the same html page.
Below is the code.

```
  <select ng-model="selectedFont" 
          ng-options="font.title for font in fonts" 
          ng-change="onFontChange()">
  </select>
```

`onFontChange()` function is placed in the controller.

Anyone help is highly appreciable...Thanks in advance.

Comment: kindly share complete code or share jsfiddle demo

Comment: i don't know about how to use jsfiddle

Comment: Can you post the code for `onFontChange()`?

Comment: Here's an example fiddle for AngularJS: http://jsfiddle.net/3y5Pw/

Comment: Most likely you're trying to get fonts from a different scope. Try to print it under the select: `{{ selectedFont }}{{ fonts }}` or install Batarang extension for Chrome browser.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Based on Tony the Pony's fiddle :

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <select ng-model="opt"
            ng-options="font.title for font in fonts"
            ng-change="change(opt)">
    </select>

    <p>{{opt}}</p>
</div>
```

With a controller:

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.fonts = [
        {title: "Arial" , text: 'Url for Arial' },
        {title: "Helvetica" , text: 'Url for Helvetica' }
    ];
    $scope.change= function(option){
        alert(option.title);
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/basarat/3y5Pw/43/

Comment: You can also use `$scope.$watch()` as stated at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15727219/how-can-i-detect-when-a-user-changes-the-value-in-a-select-drop-down-using-angul

Answer (score 3):

First create data (can be local or from server) in Controller. And initialize the default value, which force the default item selected in HTML form.

```
// supported languages
$scope.languages = ['ENGLISH', 'SPANISH', 'RUSSIAN', 'HINDI', 'NEPALI'];
// init default language
$scope.language = 'ENGLISH';
```

Now in your HTML form

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="language">
    <option ng-repeat="language in languages">{{language}}</option>
</select>
```

---

The screenshot is here (note bootstrap CSS is used and not included here).

[image]

---

You can do a test in controller, whether the change is working

```
$scope.$watch('language', function (newVal, oldVal) {
    console.log(oldVal + " -> " + newVal);
});
```

> ENGLISH -> RUSSIAN
>
> RUSSIAN -> SPANISH
>
> SPANISH -> RUSSIAN

Hope this is helpful. Thanks!