# What is strange error in Angular JS after ng-change?

Tags: angularjs

I have `ng-change` event in select list HTML:

```
<select class="form-control select short-input" ng-model="albumSelect" ng-change="selectedAlbum(albumSelect)" required>

<div ng-show="selectedAlbum == 'public'" class="cateroryArticle dropdown-checkbox dropdown"></div>
```

**Angular JS:**

```
$scope.selectedAlbum = function (item) {
   $scope.selectedAlbum = item;
}
```

When I change option in select list I get error:

> TypeError: k is not a function
>       at ib.functionCall (angular.min.js:198)
>       at l.$get.l.$eval (angular.min.js:125)
>       at angular.min.js:213
>       at angular.min.js:225
>       at s (angular.min.js:7)
>       at dg.$$writeModelToScope (angular.min.js:225)
>       at angular.min.js:225
>       at l (angular.min.js:223)
>       at g (angular.min.js:223)
>       at dg.$$runValidators (angular.min.js:224)

I can not find reason of this error. What is it may be?

Comment: You are changing function to a variable inside the function, first try changing this (different name for function and variable)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are changing function to a variable inside the function, first try changing this (different name for a function or variable).

Perhaps using a different name for a function such as:

```
<select class="form-control select short-input" ng-model="albumSelect" ng-change="selectAlbum(albumSelect)" required>
```

and then also change function to `selectAlbum` instead of `selectedAlbum`:

```
$scope.selectAlbum = function (item) {
   $scope.selectedAlbum = item;
}
```

Comment: So, after select `ng-model="albumSelect"` is empty still

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16272400/angularjs-ngmodel-directive-in-select for ng-model usage. We only filled selectedAlbum value on ng-change

Comment: Had a similar error, changed the function name per your suggestion and it worked... weird magic this is.